# iPhone: How to avoid background color coming up when button is selected?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a button with a curved image set as its foreground image. It looks like:

[image: not selected]

Now when the button is on pressed state, it shows up like this:

[image: button pressed state]

notice the grey rectangular color coming up around the edges. Is there any easy way to avoid the grey background coming all over the rectangle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the property Shows Touch On Highlight to enabled.

Programmatically you can do that with:

```
[button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```